# How to pull wordpress posts from one blog to an external blog?

Tags: plugins

I would like two sites to have exactly the same posts and pages. The second website would pull all the content from the first (images, posts, pages, etc). I tried to do it with [Broadcast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) but it requires a multisite installation if I understood correctly.

Is there a way to make my second blog pulling all its content from the first ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This plugin will do just that. It uses the RSS feed from the main blog and then posts the content onto the second blog via a cron job.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-post-importer/

Answer (score -1):

Automattic uses a plugin on WordPress VIP that enables syndication of content across different sites, and even platforms. Check out https://github.com/Automattic/syndication for the code.